# What does Java's UDP _DatagramSocket.connect()_ do?

Tags: java, sockets, udp, protocols, connection

I've recently seen the a little tutorial about Java's UDP API and I've looked at the javadocs of the `DatagramSocket` and `DatagramPacket` classes. The class `DatagramSocket` contains several `connect()` and one `disconnect()` methods. But isn't UDP a protocol without connections?

What do these `connect` and `disconnect` methods do?

Comment: While UDP is indeed connectionless, you *can* use the connect function on UDP sockets, but the semantics is different from TCP. See e.g. [this document (section 5.2)](http://www.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/documentation/unix/unix-socket-faq/unix-socket-faq-5.html) for more information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the javadocs of [DatagramSocket#connect(InetAddress address,
           int port)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#connect(java.net.InetAddress,%20int)):

> Connects the socket to a remote address for this socket. **When a socket is connected to a remote address, packets may only be sent to or received from that address.** By default a datagram socket is not connected.
>
> ...
>
> When a socket is connected, `receive` and `send` will not perform any security checks on incoming and outgoing packets, other than matching the packet's and the socket's address and port. **On a send operation, if the packet's address is set and the packet's address and the socket's address do not match, an `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown. A socket connected to a multicast address may only be used to send packets.**

So it's not really a way to establish a "connection" the same way TCP does, but a way to prevent sending or receiving packets to/from other addresses.

Answer (score 1):

One actual use case is managing concurrent calls of method `receive()`.

E.g. you have 2 separate communication flows with 2 network nodes, handled in 2
separated control flows / `Thread`-s, each of the `Thread`-s blocked on `receive` for incoming messages.

Now, with disconnected `DatagramSocket`-s it is not defined, what  `Thread` would catch what message.

But if you connect each of the sockets to the address of their corresponding node, incoming messages are delegated to the right control flow.